# Find out if a Regex could match

Tags: regex

Lets say P is a regex pattern defined as "AB" where A,B are subpatterns. There is a string T which is tested against pattern P. I want to find out if T is a partial match of P, this means T machtes against A but not B since it is not long enough to match B. T could be a match if it was combined with a string U which is matched by B.

```
var A = "[a-z]{3}";
var B = "[0-9]{2}"
var P = A + B;

var T = "abc";
var U = "20";

var macthes_T = regex(P, T); // false
var matches_U = regex(P, U); // false
var matches_TU = regex(P, T + U); // true

var couldMatch_T = magic(P, T); // true
var couldMatch_U = magic(P, U); // false
var couldMatch_TU = magic(P, T + U); // true
```

Now I want to doe this recursive on A since its the "start" of P and "implement" the magic function for input T, which would look like this:

```
var A_1 = "[a-z]";
var A_2 = "[a-z]";
var A_3 = "[a-z]";
var A = A_1 + A_2 + A_3;

// T="" would return false
// T="a" would return true
var hasChar(T) {
   return length(T) > 0;
}

// T="ab" would return a and T is "b"
var getChar(T) {
  var c = T[0];
  T = substring(T, 1);
  return c;
}

// Let x element of [a-z]
// would return true for "", "x", "xx", "xxx"
// would return false for any other input T
var magic_A(T) {
  if(!hasChar(T)) {
    return true;
  }
  if(!regex(A_1, getChar(T))) {
    return false;
  }
  if(!hasChar(T)) {
    return true;
  }
  if(!regex(A_2, getChar(T))) {
    return false;
  }
  if(!hasChar(T)) {
    return true;
  }
  if(!regex(A_3, getChar(T))) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Your question is all over the place. Please clearly state what should be matched and what shouldn't be. Also `*?+` is not valid regex. Unless you mean the characters individually. Either way `startsWith` does not work with regex...

Answer (score 0):

umm something like this?

\b(a|ab)[a-z]*

this one check if there's a or ab, then any char between a-z following behind and wrap the whole word as matching

http://regexr.com/3aa5n

just noticed that your code won't work with regex
here's some reference **http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match**